# Transmission Fluid Pump - 2008 Crown Victoria Police Interceptor P71 CVPI

Tags: engine, ford, transmission, crown-victoria

Hi, I have a 2008 Ford Crown Victoria Police Interceptor.

My car runs in forward and reverse for a short time (30 seconds to 2 minutes) and produces a loud whine noise, then acts like it's in neutral. I believe this to be the Transmission Fluid pump.
My question regards to what my best option would be.

Would it be more cost effective to just get a rebuilt engine or can I replace the Transmission Fluid Pump Gears myself? They're only about $60 if you can find someone who sells them, plus grab a master rebuild kit.

Would this be something I can tackle myself with limited mechanical expertise?

> ***Update: Rebuilt the transmission at a shop & works great now. You can have it done cheaper but my cost was $2200***

Comment: I forgot to mention after a short time it acts like it's going in neutral and will even roll backwards when in gear and on an incline, like it's in neutral. I also didn't get any action (acted like neutral) until I disconnected the sensor going to the transmission on the passenger side. That boosts fluid pressure enough to drive for a few minutes.

Comment: Update: Rebuilt the transmission & works great now. You can have it done cheaper but my cost was $2200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the transmission fluid pump is part of the transmission. In most auto transmissions it sits right behind the torque converter (which is attached to the back of the engine). In order to change one out, you need to remove the transmission. It is not something which the average person (or mechanic) can or should do. The reason for this is because if the pump is going out, this usually means it is self destructing in one manner or another, which means there are metal flakes from it circulating (at least until it hits the pan) throughout the transmission. This means the transmission is going to require a complete tear down and clean-up in order to fix it correctly. Since someone is in there cleaning it up, it's an opportune time to actually rebuild the transmission. A large chunk of the bill for repair is going to be the labor of removing it from the vehicle and such. If you have the means and ability, you could save yourself the large chuck of change by pulling and installing it yourself.

With all that said, I'm not so sure it is the pump. From the sounds of it, you have something else going on with the transmission. The noise, lack of drive-ability, ability to drive for a bit after removing the connection to the "sensor" leads me to believe it is internal to the transmission and will require a complete rebuild.

There is a problem there which is not going to go away on its own. If you continue to drive it, you run the distinct probability of damaging hard parts (if you haven't done so already). The more hard parts, the more expensive the rebuild is going to be. (Hard parts include things like gears, planetary, sprag unit, etc. Soft parts are things like the bands and clutches.)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to get a used or rebuilt transmission very easily. A used one is a crap shoot ... it could be no better than what yours is. If you go that route, ensure you get some type of warranty on it. You can get a rebuilt one, but the only way I'd do that is if mine was *completely* shot (hard parts destroyed) or if I were completely strapped for time. A shop can rebuild a transmission in a day for you. I'd just pull yours and take it down to get rebuilt. This is probably by far your best and safest bet.